# WebRTC doesn't show remote video

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I try to make WebRTC p2p application with socket.io according to O'Reilly WebRTC course. The first thing to do is initialise the peer connection with STUN server configuration:

```
var configuration = {
    'iceServers': [{
        'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }]
};
```

```
rtcPeerConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

The next part of start signaling is defining several handlers it's needed for the WebRTC connection to be established. When these is an ice-candidate ready to send to peer, this first event handler is fired and that candidate will be send over the socket.io channel to anyone on it.

```
// send any ice candidates to the other peer
rtcPeerConn.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
if (evt.candidate)
io.emit('signal',{"user_type":"signaling", "command":"icecandidate", "user_data": JSON.stringify({ 'candidate': evt.candidate })});
console.log("completed sending an ice candidate...");
};
```

The next handler is to create an offer when the peer connection tells it’s ready for negotiation

```
// let the 'negotiationneeded' event trigger offer generation
rtcPeerConn.onnegotiationneeded = function () {
console.log("on negotiation called");
rtcPeerConn.createOffer(sendLocalDesc, logError);
};
```

**Full code:**

```
io.on('signal', function(data) {

    if (myUserType == "manager") {
    // here is checking user type customer/manager and show the elements for this user type
    }
    // ... //
    else if (data.user_type == 'signaling') {
        if (!rtcPeerConn) startSignaling();
        var message = JSON.parse(data.user_data);
        if (message.sdp) {
            rtcPeerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), function () {
                // if we received an offer, we need to answer
                if (rtcPeerConn.remoteDescription.type == 'offer') {
                    rtcPeerConn.createAnswer(sendLocalDesc, logError);
                }
            }, logError);
        }
        else {
            rtcPeerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
        }
    }
});
```

Create the RTCPeerConnection:

```
function startSignaling() {
    console.log("starting signaling...");
    rtcPeerConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    // send any ice candidates to the other peer
    rtcPeerConn.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
        if (evt.candidate)
            io.emit('signal',{"user_type":"signaling", "command":"icecandidate", "user_data": JSON.stringify({ 'candidate': evt.candidate })});
        console.log("completed sending an ice candidate...");
    };

    // let the 'negotiationneeded' event trigger offer generation
    rtcPeerConn.onnegotiationneeded = function () {
        console.log("on negotiation called");
        rtcPeerConn.createOffer(sendLocalDesc, logError);
    };

    // once remote stream arrives, show it in the main video element
    rtcPeerConn.onaddstream = function (evt) {
        console.log("going to add their stream...");
        mainVideoArea.srcObject = evt.stream;
    };

    // get a local stream, show it in our video tag and add it to be sent
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        'audio': false,
        'video': true
    }, function (stream) {
        console.log("going to display my stream...");
        smallVideoArea.srcObject = stream;
        rtcPeerConn.addStream(stream);
    }, logError);

}

function sendLocalDesc(desc) {
    rtcPeerConn.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
        console.log("sending local description");
        io.emit('signal',{"user_type":"signaling", "command":"SDP", "user_data": JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': rtcPeerConn.localDescription })});
    }, logError);
}
```

Why remote video isn't shown? If anybody knows how to fix code from this course i would very much appreciate

Comment: Just a question, but from which year is the O'Reilly-Book? It uses some deprecated or discouraged function calls, like browser-prefixes for the WebRTC-API or callbacks instead of the Promise based API. Using success- and error-callbacks like you did is also deprecated since a few years, likewise is the addStream-API.

Comment: What are errors in console?